# Angular directive not working right on iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using a commonly used ionic directive to set focus to a textarea on page load which shows the ionic keyboard, and it works fine on every device I've tested with except on an iPhone 4s.

**HTML**

```
<textarea focus-me></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        element[0].focus();
      }),350;
    }
  };
});
```

On an iPhone 4s, when the textarea loses focus the keyboard disappears and then pops right back up. This doesn't happen on any other device.

How can I set focus to the textarea on page load (and subsequent page loads) and prevent the ionic keyboard from popping back up when the textarea loses focus?

Comment: Not sure if this is a copy an paste error - but your `$timeout` call is wrong. It should be  `$timeout(function() { element[0].focus(); },350);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code calling the `$timeout` directive. It should be:

```
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        element[0].focus();
      }, 350); // correct this
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Oh, hehe, woops. My bad. Now that's akward... Thanks for pointing that out.